# How to account for the huge difference in susceptibility of liquid and gaseous oxygen?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-electrodynamics, states-of-matter, matter

I noticed this while studying magnetic fields in matter from Griffiths' Electrodynamics book. A table is provided in the chapter which shows the materials with their respective susceptibilities. Under paramagnetic materials, there is oxygen and liquid oxygen(-200 degree celsius) with their susceptibilities 1.9* 10^(-6) and 3.9*10^(-3).

My question is that why is there such a huge difference between their susceptibilities when they are the same element? To be precise, is there any theory to account for this property?

Answer (score 2):

The effect of each $O_2$ molecule on the susceptibility is almost the same in both phases. The magnetic susceptibility of the liquid oxygen is about 1,000 times higher simply because it's a liquid and the density of liquids is about 1,000 times larger than the density of gases (it's more or less true whether you count the density as mass per unit volume or the number of molecules per unit volume).

Note that the density of the air is about 1.3 kilograms per cubic meter, over 700 times less than the density 1,000 kilograms per cubic meter of liquid water. A 1,000 times larger number of molecules in a volume implies approximately a 1,000 times larger effect of these molecules on the magnetic fields in the volume, i.e. a larger susceptibility.

Gases are so much lighter than liquids because the density of liquids is more or less determined by their internal structure (the molecules are tightly packed) and almost independent of the pressure. On the other hand, gases are very diluted with huge distances between the individual gas molecules. And the density is more or less directly proportional to the pressure. When we talk about the density of gases, we usually happen to talk about the gases at the atmospheric pressure on Earth. The atmospheric pressure on Earth is so low that gases are typically 1,000 times lighter than liquids. The atmospheric pressure is so low because it's caused by a relatively "light" column of gases in the atmosphere at each point.